# VPS with OS, etc managed by vendor?

Tags: hosting

I want to find somewhere to host a web app that has a Python (Django) front-end, and a Java back-end (basically, a crawler). The obvious candidates are Slicehost, Linode or even Amazon EC2 - however it seems that like most VPS systems, you have to manage all aspects of sys admin, like keeping it patched, etc.

While I can admin a box if I must, I'm a developer first and foremost and want to be able to focus on that, rather than worrying about getting paged at 1am because someone just compromised my box, the log files filled up the disk, or any one of the other zillion things that can happen if you're not properly managing your servers.

Google App engine would have been nice, but it doesn't allow Java apps to access to threads and sockets, both of which are required but key parts of the Java part of the app.

Maybe I just need to bite the bullet and accept that I need to get used to being a sysadmin as well as a developer, but I'd appreciate any suggestions for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of getting nailed for spamming, the company I work for, [Anchor Systems](http://www.anchor.com.au/) does managed VPS (and dedicated server) products, where we do all of the low-level management (monitoring, security updates, emergency fault resolution, etc) and help you with advice on the "bigger issues" like capacity upgrades and such.

(If anyone *really* does think this is spam, let me know in a comment and I'll remove it)